# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator Database migrate

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 EI 6.5.0 (latest release),

I'm wondering that Where can i find WSO2 database schema, stores all of things,

Those log files, written on Management console is saved in Database right ? 
I am using Oracle DB (PL\SQL)..

I found oracle.sql from dbscripts folder - %E_HOME%,

How to connect WSO2's default database in PLSQL ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

By default wsoesb use h2 database. You can overwrite default database using oracle. There is documentation how to configure datasource, and there is, i am not sure something like carbon.xml where configure default datasource.

Answer (score 0):

No, the logs are persisted in the files in ESB_HOME/repository/logs folder.

As @srimar mentioned, the default database is embedded H2. You can follow this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Browsing+the+H2+Database) to browse the embedded H2. 
But WSO2 didn't recommend the embedded H2 database in the production

To configure the Oracle database you can follow this [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Setting+up+Oracle)

Comment: Thanks i set default database to oracle
So Then Log files are not saved in Database ?